# Laravel 7: Connect 3 tables using models

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-7, laravel-models

I have three different tables:

- Users: ID, name, etc...
- Teams: ID, creator_id, etc...
- Team_Action: ID, team_id, etc...
- Permissions: ID, name, etc...

Team_Action has a FK (action_id) with Perimissions which I need the **name** value of that table.
Team_Action also has a FK (user_id) with Users which I need the **name** value of the users table.

At the time, I can only access ID's and not names.

I was wondering if there is any way to achieve the following by only using Laravel's models:

```
@foreach($team->teamAction as $tmdata)
<tr>
  <td>
    $team->teamMember->name
  </td>
  <td>
   $team->teamAction->name
  </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

my Team model:

```
    //Infinite users belong to a team
public function teamMembers() {
    return $this->hasMany(TeamsMembers::class,'team_id','id');
}

    //Infinite actions per team
public function teamAction(){
    return $this->hasMany(TeamsAction::class);
}
```

TeamAction

```
    public function team(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Team::class);
}
```

Permission

```
public function teamAction(){
return $this->belongsTo(TeamsAction::class,'action_id');}
```

TeamsMembers

```
    public function team() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Team::class,'team_id','id');
}
public function teamMember(){
    return $this->hasMany(User::class,'id','user_id');
}
```

My controllers code:

```
$teamID = $request->route('id');
$team = Team::where('id',$teamID)->get()->first();
        

        foreach ($team->teamAction as $tta) {
            $allTeamActions = Permission::where('id', $tta->action_id)->get();
        }

        foreach ($team->teamMembers as $ttm){
            $allTeamMembers = User::where('id', $ttm->user_id)->get();
        }
```

I am aiming for something like this

```
$allTeamActions = Permission::where('id', $team->teamAction[0]->action_id->name)->get();
```

EDIT:
Let me put on some visuals to make it more clear:
[image]

Is there a way to retrieve through eloquent models the name values which are FK's of those models to the model I am using?
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAJ4W.png)

The scenario is the following:
Each member belongs to a Team. (Table Teams: ID, creator_id)
The team has multiple members in another table named team_members (user_id, team_id).
A team has multiple actions stored in another table named team_actions which store FK values coming from another table named permissions (team_id,action_id_user_id).
A user table stores all the actual information of the users (aka their names which I'd like to use)

I want to create a view table with all that information.
Namely, I am trying though the Teams model to access the following information:
**Team users** (their names coming from users table, the ID of the user is stored in team_members and team_actions)

**Team user actions** (the name of the action coming from the permission table, the ID of the action is stored in team_actions)

Comment: I think I am confused on which one of my tables is considered a "pivot". Also, when I try allTeamActions without specifying a key value (0 in my example) I get nothing in return.

Comment: This is not true in my case. A team hasMany teamActions but teamActions belongTo team

Comment: You question is still not clear and very confusing the tables you mentioned didn't match with the no. of models, can you add a brief description of your scenario

Comment: You are right. I will try to rephrase my question

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid please see my rephrased question

Comment: Another question what is the difference between `team_members` and `team_actions` because team action table has team_id ,user_id & action_id so I guess you can extract team members from this table and `team_members` is of no use. If there is any specific reason please mention

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid The only difference between them is that team_actions has action_id inside it. Other than that, they are the same

Comment: So can we remove team_members table ? because it redundant as we can get information of team members from team_actions table right ?

Comment: Exactly. But the model relation will still return an ID and not the actual name of the value. What I want is to get the associated name of the foreign keys

Answer (score 1):

As per the provided description `team_actions` table look like a pivot or junction table which forms a many to many relation between team <-> users & team <-> permissions. Based on this conclusion you can define a `hasMany()` relation to `team_actions` table which will be a `TeamMemberAction` model

```
class TeamMemberAction extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'team_actions';

    public function member()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'id', 'user_id');
    }
    public function team()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Team::class, 'id', 'team_id');
    }
    public function action()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Permission::class, 'id', 'action_id');
    }
}


class Team extends Model
{
    
    public function member_actions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(TeamMemberAction::class, 'id', 'team_id');
    }
}
```

---

So I guess there is no need for additional `team_members` table just to get the team members list.

Now with this new mapping you can get the members and actions as

```
$team = Team:with(['member_actions.member','member_actions.action'])->find(1);
```

---

For member name you will need to loop `$team->member_action` collection, and each collection will have a member key with member details from user table same goes for actions like

```
{
    id:1
    name:"Team One"
    member_actions: [{
            id: 3,
            member: {
                id: 7
                name: "User name"
            },
            action: {
                id: 11,
                name: "Action name"
            }
        },{
            id: 5
            member: {
                id: 9,
                name: "User name"
            },
            action: {
                id: 13,
                name: "Action name"
            }
        }]
}
```

---

If you directly want the team members then you an define belongs to many relations in your team model as

```
class Team extends Model
{
    public function members()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'team_actions', 'team_id', 'user_id');
    }
    public function actions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Permission::class, 'team_actions', 'team_id', 'action_id');
    }

}
```

---

Then you can eager load both relations as

```
$team = Team:with(['members','actions'])->find(1);
```

---

```
{
    id:1
    name:"Team One"
    members: [{
            id: 3,
            name: "User name"
        },{
            id: 5,
            name: "User name"
    }],
    actions: [{
            id: 7,
            name: "Action name"
        },{
            id: 9,
            name: "Action name"
    }]
}
```

Comment: I pretty much could simply select the member_actions table which connect both users and actions tables.

Comment: @GeorgeG I didn't get your point, is there any thing missing ? or any issue ?